# LINQ query for multiple join tables in C#

Tags: c#, linq

In my application, I have to write a query that displays data from a number of the tables. In other words, I have to create a query that will make a join for number of tables and will show wanted information from this query.
The query has to display all the events (and all data about the events in `DataGrid`) for a specific (chosen) worker.

Here is a code of my LINQ:

```
IList dataList = (from dWorker in App.glidusContext.tbl_workers
    where dWorker.workerTZ == strSplit
    join d2 in App.glidusContext.tbl_workers_has_tbl_events
    on dWorker.workerID equals d2.workerID
    join dEvent in App.glidusContext.tbl_events
    on d2.eventID equals dEvent.eventID
    join dAct in App.glidusContext.tbl_activities
    on d2.eventID equals dAct.eventID
    select new { d2.damagedVacantionEnd, dEvent, dAct }).ToList();

return dataList;
```

Where `strSplit` is a specific (chosen) worker.

XAML-code of `DataGrid`:

```xml
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.WinSafetyByEmployee_DataGrid_ColHead_Event_type}"
        Width="130"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        Binding="{Binding Path=dEvent.tbl_eventsType.eventTypeName}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.WinSafetyByEmployee_DataGrid_ColHead_Classification}"
        Width="130"
        Binding="{Binding Path=dEvent.tbl_eventsClassification.eventClassificationName}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.WinSafetyByEmployee_DataGrid_ColHead_Catagory}"
        Width="130"
        Binding="{Binding Path=dEvent.tbl_eventsCategories.eventCategoryName}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.WinSafetyByEmployee_DataGrid_ColHead_Evacuation}"
        Width="130"
        Binding="{Binding Path=d2.damagedEvacuationDescription}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.WinSafetyByEmployee_DataGrid_ColHead_EvacuationStart}"
        Width="130"
        Binding="{Binding Path=d2.damagedVacantionStart}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.WinSafetyByEmployee_DataGrid_ColHead_EvacuationEnd}"
        Width="130"
        Binding="{Binding Path=d2.damagedVacantionEnd}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.WinSafetyByEmployee_DataGrid_ColHead_ActivityName}"
        Width="*"
        Binding="{Binding Path=dAct.activityName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How to fix this query? Now this variant doesn't return values.

I also cannot reach tbl_objects in the query because I need to do it thought the connection table `tbl_object_has_tbl_events` and `App.glidus` do not show such a table.

Here is an ERD of my database:

[image: DB ERD]

Comment: If you open the dbml file of your database in visual studio, does the class tbl_objects_has_tbl_events show up or not ? If it does, could you open the generated designer.cs class, copy the class tbl_objects_has_tbl_events and paste it in your question ? Also, how do you generate your dbml file, by hand or through a tool (sqlmetal for example) ?

Comment: Hi, Actually I'm using ADO.NET Entity Framework and generate EDMX-file, not DBML. EDMX file I get by Visual Studio Whizard, where I set SQL Server instance, choose DB and select all tables in this DB. After that it generates ERD and I can access to table via auto-generated classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (I'm not sure exactly what your navigation properties will be called) :

```
IList dataList = (from we in App.glidusContext.tbl_workers_has_tbl_events
                  where we.worker.workerTZ == strSplit
                  select new { we.damagedVacantionEnd, 
                               we.tbl_event, 
                               we.tbl_event.tbl_activity}).ToList();

return dataList;
```

**Update:**

Also, looking at you xaml, you are trying to bind to properties that aren't returned in you anonymous type. eg `d2.damagedVacantionStart` - you have not returned the entire `d2` object so cannot bind to other properties on it, not have access to `d2`.

Try simplifying things by returning the exact properties you need in your query and binding directly to those. eg

```
select new { VacStart = we.damagedVacantionStart, 
             VacEnd = we.damagedVacantionEnd, 
             EvTypeName = we.tbl_event.tbl_eventsType.eventTypeName, 
             ...}).ToList();
```

Then in your xaml you can have simple binding expressions:

```
Binding="{Binding Path=evTypeName}" />
```

Comment: Code of my query returns exception entityCommandExecutionException.

Comment: @Toucki - Your code or mine? Look at the innerException to see if it has more information about what caused the exception. You don't need to manually do all those joins - thats part of the benefits of using Linq to Entities. It provides the navigation properties between tables and handles the joins under the covers. When writing the query, intellisense should help you work out what the navigation properties are called.

Comment: @ Geoff Appleford, My code returhs exception, I'll check your solution and will write about results. Thanks.

Comment: Is all what you are saying is also relevant to ADO.NET Entity Framework? I'm using this way to interact with DB (EDMX-file).

Comment: The problem is that we can't access to association class (connection table that stores primary keys of two differen tables)
we.tbl_event.tbl_objects_has_tbl_events.select(e => e.tbl_object)
We can't touch this connection table and we even don't see this table in ERD inside of Visual Studio 2010 Diagram viewer.

Comment: @Toucki Does `tbl_events` have a collection of `tbl_objects`? eg Can you do `we.tbl_event.tbl_objects)` See http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/inserting-many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-with-or-without-a-join-entity/

Comment: No, **tbl_events** doesn't contain any reference collection to **tbl_objects**.